# table - merge multiple <th>& <td> into single <tr> <th> with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have use table structure in below my HTML design page, but I want to click on button
Event and I want to my output define on below html page

```
<div>
        <button type="button" class="btnmergecell imgClass2" style="float: left"></button>
        <br />
        <table id="tblClaimedbyOthers">
            <thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="iconth" width="300px">

                        <span class="col-center">Intake User</span>
                    </th>
                    <td> abc </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="iconth" width="300px">
                        <span class="col-center">Billing</span>
                    </th>
                    <td> def </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="iconth" width="300px">
                        <span class="col-center">Pharmacist</span>
                    </th>
                    <td> pqr </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </thead>         
         </table>
        <table id="tblClaimedbyOthers">
            <thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="iconth" width="300px">
                            <span class="col-center">Intake User</span>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td> abc </td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="iconth" width="300px">
                        <span class="col-center">Billing</span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr><td> def </td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="iconth" width="300px">
                        <span class="col-center">Pharmacist</span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> pqr </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </thead>
       </table>
    </div>
```

```
Input

Intake User     abc
Billing         def
Pharmacist      pqr

Output

Intake User
Abc
Billing
Def
Pharmacist
pqr
```

Comment: jsfiddle would be helpful

Comment: Can you clearly define your problem and what do u want to achieve???

Comment: You want to create 2nd table dynamically? or change current table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IF YOU WANT TO CREATE A YOUR OUTPUT TABLE AS NEW TABLE, YOU CAN TRY THIS CODE,**

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    var newTable = '<table id="tb2ClaimedbyOthers" border="1"><thead><tbody>';
    $('#tblClaimedbyOthers tr').each(function () {
        newTable += '<tr><th class="iconth" width="300px"><span class="col-center">' + $(this).find('th span').html() + '</span></th></tr><tr><td>' + $(this).find('th').next().html() + '</td></tr>';
    });
    newTable += ' </tbody></thead> </table>';
    $( "body" ).append(newTable);
});
```

**SEE THIS [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/rsuht/)**

**IF YOU WANT YOUR OUTPUT TABLE IN THE SAME TABLE, YOU CAN TRY THIS CODE,**

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    var newTable = '<table id="tb2ClaimedbyOthers" border="1"><thead><tbody>';
    $('#tblClaimedbyOthers tr').each(function () {
        newTable += '<tr><th class="iconth" width="300px"><span class="col-center">' + $(this).find('th span').html() + '</span></th></tr><tr><td>' + $(this).find('th').next().html() + '</td></tr>';
    });
    newTable += ' </tbody></thead> </table>';
    $( "#tblClaimedbyOthers" ).html(newTable);
});
```

**SEE THIS [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/rsuht/3/)**